# xbuild fails to build .csproj on raspbian

Tags: raspbian, software-compilation, mono

I am trying to build a C#-project (written on windows, copied to the Pi):

> root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# xbuild MDD_Basic.csproj

Which leads to two error messages and the build inevitably failing.
Here's the error message:

```
XBuild Engine Version 12.0 Mono, Version 3.2.8.0 Copyright (C) 2005-2013 Various Mono authors Build started 9/9/2014 4:07:57 PM. 
__________________________________________________ Project "/home/pi/MDD_Basic/MDD_Basic.csproj" (default target(s)):
    Target PrepareForBuild:
        Configuration: Debug Platform: AnyCPU /usr/lib/mono/4.5/Microsoft.Common.targets: error : Invalid handle to path 
"/home/pi/MDD_Basic/obj/Debug/" at System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectoriesInternal (System.String path) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory (System.String path) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.MakeDir.Execute () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
    Task "MakeDir" execution -- FAILED
    Done building target "PrepareForBuild" in project "/home/pi/MDD_Basic/MDD_Basic.csproj".-- FAILED
    Target _RecordCleanFile: /usr/lib/mono/4.5/Microsoft.Common.targets: error : Could not find a part of the path 
"/home/pi/MDD_Basic/obj/Debug/MDD_Basic.csproj.FilesWrittenAbsolute.txt".  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, FileMode mode, 
FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean anonymous, FileOptions options) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.FileStream:.ctor (string,System.IO.FileMode,System.IO.FileAccess,System.IO.FileShare)
  at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor (System.String path, Boolean append, System.Text.Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize) [0x00000] in <filename 
unknown>:0
  at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor (System.String path, Boolean append) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.StreamWriter:.ctor (string,bool)
  at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.WriteLinesToFile.Execute () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
    Task "WriteLinesToFile" execution -- FAILED
    Done building target "_RecordCleanFile" in project "/home/pi/MDD_Basic/MDD_Basic.csproj".-- FAILED Done building project 
"/home/pi/MDD_Basic/MDD_Basic.csproj".-- FAILED Build FAILED. Errors: /home/pi/MDD_Basic/MDD_Basic.csproj (default targets) -> 
/usr/lib/mono/4.5/Microsoft.Common.targets (PrepareForBuild target) ->
    /usr/lib/mono/4.5/Microsoft.Common.targets: error : Invalid handle to path "/home/pi/MDD_Basic/obj/Debug/" at 
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectoriesInternal (System.String path) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory (System.String path) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.MakeDir.Execute () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 /home/pi/MDD_Basic/MDD_Basic.csproj (default targets) -> 
/usr/lib/mono/4.5/Microsoft.Common.targets (_RecordCleanFile target) ->
    /usr/lib/mono/4.5/Microsoft.Common.targets: error : Could not find a part of the path 
"/home/pi/MDD_Basic/obj/Debug/MDD_Basic.csproj.FilesWrittenAbsolute.txt".  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, FileMode mode, 
FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean anonymous, FileOptions options) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.FileStream:.ctor (string,System.IO.FileMode,System.IO.FileAccess,System.IO.FileShare)
  at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor (System.String path, Boolean append, System.Text.Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize) [0x00000] in <filename 
unknown>:0
  at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor (System.String path, Boolean append) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.StreamWriter:.ctor (string,bool)
  at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.WriteLinesToFile.Execute () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
     0 Warning(s)
     2 Error(s) Time Elapsed 00:00:09.5757510
```

To me it looks like it failed to create a directory and access a file.
Therefore I ran the whole thing as root once, to see wether that helps.

So does anyone have an idea why this is not working?

Comment: what parts of the path "/home/pi/MDD_Basic/obj/Debug/MDD_Basic.csproj.FilesWrittenAbsolute.txt" do you have?

Comment: @rob all Dirs, just not the file. Also I'm used to xbuild making the dirs it needs.